# Kendo MVC Grid Update Model Mapping Fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo MVC Grid, which fails to map the parameter when creating / updating new record.

Below is my chrome network for the request:

[image]

I try to get `DTO` & `row` in my action, now the strange point is, `DTO` is passed successfully, but `row` did not , as shown below.

[image]

Below is my class of `row` , for your reference

[image]

What is the possible causes that `row` cannot be mapped successfully?
And how can I fix it and get the value in my action?

**EDITED**

If I simply list all fields in the model (and change some JS so that only send the data in `row`), all fields are bound successfully..

Only if I use the class of the model as the parameter will make it fail...which supposed to be success...

```js
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult MaterialGrid_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string Bin, string Storeroom, string ItemCode, string ItemDescription, long ItemMoveID, string JobDescription, string JobNo, decimal Quantity, string TransactionCode, string TransactionType, DateTime TransactionTime, WorkOrderInfoViewModel DTO)
   {


     return Json("");
   }
```

Comment: could you please your grid code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `{ get; set; }` to your View model properties.

```
public class MaterialGridViewModel
{
    public string Bin {get;set;}
    ......
```

Comment: Stupid me, yes it is the correct solution. Short, simple yet correct